# Displaying web page in Ionic V4 app - inconsistencies

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have used the following for years to display an external website in my own Ionic apps with no issues:

```
<a href="https://www.golftocs.com/" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px;">
  golfTOCS
</a>
```

I recently inherited an Ionic V4 app that uses cordova-plugin-inappbrowser to display external websites, per the plug-in documentation. I try to use my already working solution, i.e. without in app browser, from my apps so I can potentially remove the in app browser plugin. However this does not work!

When I make this change the app transitions to the external website but it is not completely functional and there is no back to app button at top left. Same operation on both Android and iOS. This is driving me crazy and I just want to understand why.

Both apps are on Ionic V4 production, Angular 7.x.x, and pretty much latest version of all plugins. I have compared node_modules, plugins, config.xml. I have tried swapping the urls between working and not working apps - not dependent on urls.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The InAppBrowser lets you control this very thing, to open the webpage in the app or a new window etc. so I'm not sure why you're worried about using that dependency? I use something like `this.iab.create('http://...', 'system')` and that works very well.

Comment: Thank you and of course this works. I'm just trying to understand what appears to be inconsistencies between my 2 Ionic V4 apps. Curious minds.

Comment: Are the whitelisting settings on the new app consistent with your old app i.e. `<allow-navigation>` and `<allow-intent>` in config.xml?

Comment: Thank you. `<allow-navigation href="*" />` is in the app using InAppBrowser, but not in my own app. When I put this line in config.xml of my own app, then viewing an external website does not work. With or w/out it in the app using InAppBrowser works find! I think I should remove this from the app, since it is not recommended per Apache Cordova docs. Anyway, that's it and if you submit as an answer then I will mark it answered. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#allow-intent), `<allow-intent>` controls which sites your app can navigate to externally and `<allow-navigation>` controls which sites your app can navigate to internally, i.e. within the WebView. Try setting `<allow-intent href="*" />` to see if it solves your problem in the new app, as well as `<allow-navigation href="*" />` as per your comment.

Both apps probably have cordova-plugin-whitelist pre-installed, so [those docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/index.html#intent-whitelist) might be able to help.

Also, begin with a generous [Content Security Policy](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/index.html#content-security-policy) as that can add an additional layer of complication ([MDN docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)).

Once working, be sure to make your policies as strict as possible and as loose as necessary.